# Laravel - 5.4v and 5.8v differences in foreign key

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, forum

What are differences in foreign key for Laravel 5.4 version and Laravel 5.8 version? I tried to install `devdojo/chatter` on my 5.8 version Laravel project and at migrating it shows me all kind of errors for foreign key, but when I try it on 5.4 version it works pretty well, no errors at all. Please help, I can't find solution and I need it in my project. Thanks!

This is my error:
`` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `cdm`.`chatter_discussion` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `chatter_discussion` add constraint `chatter_discussion_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade) ``

This is my `chatter_discussion` table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateChatterDiscussionTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('chatter_category_id')->unsigned()->default('1');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('sticky')->default(false);
            $table->integer('views')->unsigned()->default('0');
            $table->boolean('answered')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('chatter_discussion');
    }
}
```

And this is `foreign_keys` table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateForeignKeys extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('chatter_category_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_categories')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
        Schema::table('chatter_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('chatter_discussion_id')->references('id')->on('chatter_discussion')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                        ->onDelete('cascade')
                        ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('chatter_discussion_chatter_category_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('chatter_discussion_user_id_foreign');
        });
        Schema::table('chatter_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('chatter_post_chatter_discussion_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('chatter_post_user_id_foreign');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please post an error you get.

Comment: I will post error and my migrations sir, just a moment

Comment: @HafezDivandari I added my error and table

Comment: @HafezDivandari and my ```foreign_key``` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Laravel 5.4, all `id` columns are type `increments` by default but On Laravel 5.8 it is `bigIncrements` by default. So change `user_id` column type to `bigInteger` on `chatter_discussion` table will fix your problem:

```php
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Remember that your local key and foreign key should always have the same type on your migrations.

Comment: I changed it and it works. But now I have another error ``` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `cdm`.`chatter_discussion` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter table `chatter_discussion` add constraint `chatter_discussion_chatter_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`chatter_category_id`) references `chatter_categories` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)```

Comment: @Milos try to rollback your previous migration and do migrate again. `php artisan migrate:rollback` and then `php artisan migrate`

Comment: What do you mean rollback ? You mean ```php artisan migrate:fresh``` or something else ?

Comment: @Milos Your table has been already created you have to rollback by using `php artisan migrate:rollback` and do migrate again or use `php artisan migrate:fresh` with caution that drops all your table and migrates again. refer to docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Comment: I just did my ```migrate:rollback``` and it worked fine without any errors, but after ```php artisan migrate``` it shows me error :```SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `cdm`.`chatter_post` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `chatter_post` add constraint `chatter_post_chatter_discussion_id_foreign` foreign key (`chatter_discussion_id`) references `chatter_discussion` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)``` and I changed this to ```chatter_discussion_id``` from ```integer``` to ```bigInteger```

Comment: And after that ```php artisan migrate``` and it shows error : ``` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `cdm`.`chatter_discussion` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter table `chatter_discussion` add constraint `chatter_discussion_chatter_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`chatter_category_id`) references `chatter_categories` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)``` some duplicate key on write or update

Comment: @Milos re-ckeck your local/foreign keys to have same types, then call `php artisan migrate:fresh` to drop all tables and migarte again.

Comment: Sir I founded the solution! I re-check every local/foreign keys as you said and return it to ```bigInteger``` and now it works. Thank you so much and sorry for bothering you

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue at https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter/issues/257 describing this.

The problem is the [boilerplate user migration](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php) primary key changed from `increments` to `bigIncrements` you therefore need to change the references:

```
class CreateChatterDiscussionTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('chatter_discussion', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('chatter_category_id')->unsigned()->default('1');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('sticky')->default(false);
            $table->integer('views')->unsigned()->default('0');
            $table->boolean('answered')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('chatter_discussion');
    }
}
```

Note: The github issue suggests changing the user migration but I strongly suggest you don't do that since there's good reason it was changed to begin with. You'll probably be fine if you do but you never know.

Comment: Yes I changed it and it works now, but it shows me another error : ``` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `cdm`.`chatter_discussion` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (SQL: alter table `chatter_discussion` add constraint `chatter_discussion_chatter_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`chatter_category_id`) references `chatter_categories` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)```